# IntelliJIDEA + Eclipse

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Добрый день!
Я работаю в команде, где большинство сидят на Eclipse, а я - на IntelliJIDEA. Все мы работаем над одним проектом и пользуемся одним *SVN* репозиторием. Как мне организовать работу, что бы при коммитах не портить Eclipse-проект, а при апдейте - свой? Дайте советы.

Comment: Перейти на ant/maven/etc, чтобы не зависеть от используемой IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать систему сборки (gradle, maven, ant). Gradle и maven умеют генерировать файлы проектов для eclipse и idea. Так же idea и eclipse умеют работать с gradle напрямую.

Comment: праивльно ли я вас понял : я использую систему сборки, вношу изменения в проект и заливаю на свн. Коллега делает апдейт,вызывает систему сборки и там делает ему , скажем, настроенные файлы проекта на *Eclipse* ? Eclipse и IntelliJ умеют сами вызывать системы сборки, что бы те для них сделали проектные файлы?

Comment: я так понимаю, что @Mage агитирует за ручную сборку. Да, она более гибкая, но в некоторых случаях отдадка с под ide стает очень сложной и компиляция долгой.

Comment: Да, так и надо делать - gradle, maven, ant, но только для сборки на buils сервере... не для генерации проектных файлов. Это просто не получится, я после каждого upade'а проект не закрываю, чтобы файлы перегенерить.

Если вы думаете, что у idea поддержка gradle, значит не работали с большим проектом (более миллиона строк кода и куча подпроектов).

Локально лучше всё же пользоваться сборщиком самой ide.

Comment: Я работаю с большим проектом, в котором много модулей и кода. Gradle использую для сборки на ci сервере и как удобный инструмент для генерации файлов проекта идеи. В последней 13 версии поддержка Gradle очень хорошая. Естественно что один раз открыв проект в идее далее я пользуюсь средствами самой среды (компиляция, отладка и прочее).

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov не стоит делать какие-то выводы если не обладаете полной информацией. С gradle я работаю примерно года 3 и это лучший инструмент для сборки джаза и груви проектов любой сложности.

Comment: @Mage да я не отрицаю, что Gradle лучший.
Я говорю, что IntelliJ не лучшим образом работает с Gradle проектом.
> не стоит делать какие-то выводы если не обладаете полной информацией
Не хотел обидеть.

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov IDEA 13 очень хорошо работает сейчас с Gradle-проектом. Да проблемы бывают, но от версии к версии все становится лучше. Сейчас можно спокойно открыть более-менее сложный проект прямо скормив IDEA build.gradle. Даже артефакты war-файлов создает для веб-модулей.

Answer (score 3):

Поместить файлы проекта в ignore lis SVN (в idea это *.iml и вся папка .idea).
Или всех на IntelliJ перевести)

Comment: а если я внес изменения в проект, залил. При этом папка эклипса *.methadata* не изменится и моим коллегам прийдется перестраивать ее!

Comment: Есть такая [приблуда](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/949?pr=) к idea. Она смотрит в эклипсовый проект и перестраивает idea. Есть плугины и для обратной задачи.

Но в целом, при коммандной работе, тимлид должен определить базовый тул, а все несогласные либо меняют работу, либо подсраиваются. Либо просто стают тимлидом:)

Comment: @voipp, если вы не знаете что происходит с проектом, значит вы не одна команда.

И всё-таки если даже одной IDE пользуетесь файлы проекта лучше не commit'ить в repository'й, иначе постоянный конфликт при merge'е